# Issue when I deploy my app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudinary

I deployed my website on heroku. My `cloudinary_url` on heroku is well set. I'm adding translation to the website via i18n gem. Here are my `new` and `create` actions from my declaration controller:

```
def new
 @declaration = Declaration.new
end

def create
  @declaration = Declaration.new(declaration_params)
  @declaration.record = Record.where(imei: @declaration.imei).first
  @declaration.type_outage << params[:declaration][:type_outage]

  create_ticket_result = FreshdeskApi.new.manage_declaration(@declaration)

  if create_ticket_result && @declaration.save
    # Les emails sont gérés dans Freshdesk
    # UserMailer.after_declaration_prs(@declaration).deliver_now
    # UserMailer.after_declaration(@declaration).deliver_now
    flash[:notice] = "Vous avez bien déclaré votre panne, Vous recevrez une réponse sous peu."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Un problème est survenu..."
    render :new
  end
end
```

When I tried to reach a page, an error occurred. In my heroku log, here's what I have:

```
2018-06-10T19:03:31.771776+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-06-10T19:03:31.771705 #4]  INFO -- : [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2018-06-10T19:03:31.772528+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-10T19:03:31.772455 #4] FATAL -- : [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]   
2018-06-10T19:03:31.772595+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-10T19:03:31.772524 #4] FATAL -- : [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446] ActionView::Template::Error (Must supply cloud_name):
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773068+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-10T19:03:31.773001 #4] FATAL -- : [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]     796:                 <div class="title-declaration">Votre facture d'achat</div>
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773070+00:00 app[web.1]: [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]     797:                 <div class="autour-facture">
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773072+00:00 app[web.1]: [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]     798:                   <div class="facture-upload">
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773073+00:00 app[web.1]: [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]     799:                     <%= f.input :facture, as: :attachinary, label: 'IMPORTER VOTRE FACTURE' %>
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773082+00:00 app[web.1]: [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]     800:                     <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 34px;"><span style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;font-family: monospace;display:block">PDF</span></i>
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773084+00:00 app[web.1]: [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]     801: 
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773087+00:00 app[web.1]: [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]     802:                   </div>
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773131+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-10T19:03:31.773059 #4] FATAL -- : [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446]   
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773207+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-10T19:03:31.773139 #4] FATAL -- : [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446] app/views/declarations/new.html.erb:799:in `block in _app_views_declarations_new_html_erb___3664345609896457777_69823217213900'
2018-06-10T19:03:31.773209+00:00 app[web.1]: [efb3e575-07c5-481b-a015-30f106c09446] app/views/declarations/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_declarations_new_html_erb___3664345609896457777_69823217213900'
```

I don't know where that "must supply `cloud name`" came from.

Comment: Can you confirm how was this cloudinary account created, also post your cloudinary.yml file

Comment: An other developer created this account. And it worked well before. I don't have a cloudinary file as i'm using figaro, so everything is in my application.yml.

Comment: heroku config:add CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://API_KEY:API_SECRET@CLOUD_NAME, use this command to manually define the variable for Heroku application

Comment: I did it but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you forgot to configure your `CLOUDINARY_URL`. See [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/Codeminer42/cm42-central/issues/185#issuecomment-305567680).

The command to do so on heroku is:

```
heroku config:add CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://API_KEY:API_SECRET@CLOUD_NAME
```

Comment: I did that, but I still have the same error ... Makes me crazy.

Comment: Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: Have you got the solution?